# Is there a hashtag on the English wireless keyboard?

Tags: keyboard

I have a wireless keyboard and can't find the hashtag. I have found it on my iPhone but can't find it on the mac keyboard

Comment: I have just found my answer in another message, Alt 3 gives the # that i have been looking for for a long time

Comment: pleas provide a link to that question or answer (note we don't have messages here)

Answer (score 2):

If  Shift 3 doesn't produce #, then try Option/alt 3.

Another less likely possibility is the \ key at the far right.

It all depends on which layout (US/ABC, British, British PC) you have active in system prefs/keyboard/input sources.  Change it to the one that matches the printing on your hardware.